# How to call a function on page load in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to call the function `startBarcodeScanner()` on page load in React but my current method keeps throwing errors. Here is my code:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// Electron related imports
const electron = window.require('electron');
const { ipcRenderer } = electron;
const loadBalancer = window.require('electron-load-balancer');

class MainPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            single: undefined,
            thread: {

            }
        };
    } 

    componentDidMount() {
       // 3. Setup listener for barcode scanner python output (bounced from main process)
        ipcRenderer.on('BARCODE_SCANNER_RESULT', (event, args) => {
            console.log(args)
            this.setState(
                {
                    ...this.state,
                    thread: {
                        ...this.state.thread,
                        [args.data.threadID]: this.state.thread[args.data.threadID] ?
                            [...this.state.thread[args.data.threadID], args.data.result] :
                            [args.data.result]
                    }
                }
            )
        });


        this.startBarcodeScanner()
 

        
    }

    startBarcodeScanner = () => {
         
        console.log("Start barcode scanner initiated!")
        loadBalancer.sendData(
            ipcRenderer,
            'barcode_scanner',
            {
                command: "BARCODE_SCANNER"
              
            }
        );
    }
   
 
    render() {
        return  (
            <div > 
                 <div>
                    <button >
                        <span>start</span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <h3>Welcome to the WalmartX </h3>
                <small>Please scan your barcode to start shopping</small>
                <Link to="/home">You are Most Welcome</Link>
            </div>

            )
    }
};

export default MainPage;
```

When I use the onclick method, everything works fine but whenever I call it in componentDidMount in the way shown above I get this error

> **A JavaScript error occurred in the main process**

> Uncaught Exception:
> TypeError: Cannot read property 'windowObject' of undefined
> at IpcMainImpl. (/Users/app/node_modules/electron-load-balancer/index.js:73:26)
> at IpcMainImpl.emit (events.js:223:5)
> at WebContents. (electron/js2c/browser_init.js:4097:15)
> at WebContents.emit (events.js:223:5)

what could be causing this error and how can I call the function on page load?

Comment: undefined doesn't it mean that your `barcodeScanner` dom element is not detected?

Comment: Maybe the way your write the code. 

Can you try `onClick={() => this.startBarcodeScanner}`

Comment: @Khant the onclick function works fine. its calling   this.startBarcodeScanner() that's throwing error

Comment: obviously ur "startBarcodeScanner" will be called just write it at first line of componentDidMount

Comment: Maybe 
I am not sure but its related to `life cycle method` of react classes.

the way you setup is like making a `clicklistener` run automatically even before the `target dom` element is loaded.

I am not sure u notice but when you call the `get request` inside the `component did mount`. The first render always return an empty `object` or `array`. 
Then at the second render the component start loading data into their respective dom elements then update it. People usually doesn't notice this behavior because these 2 renders happen simultaneously.

PS NOT SURE ABOUT THIS